# How to implement complex security rules in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, model-view-controller

I have a system I'm building that seems to call for some complex rules and rather than have a mess of rules through out the system. I was looking to centralize the process. (Which may not be the smartest idea I've had)

My most (perhaps least) brilliant idea was to use a seperate class to check any objects before being saved to the database against a list of allowed values in various fields. It's extremely tightly bound to the database structure but rather easily testable and easy to maintain.

Examples of rules:

- Moderators can submit comments with moderator status but not admin status.

  - *Comments.status can only be normal or moderator (admin is reserved for administrators)*
- Users can not modify moderator value on comments

  - *Comments.status can only be normal, Comments.display can only be normal*
- Only moderators can suspend user accounts

  - *list of numerous fields*
- Only moderators can modify other user accounts

  - *restriction on which fields with logic to determine if the current user owns the row*
- Only users with paid accounts can do X, Y, and Z.

The problem I'm having is where do I put this logic. It's getting far too complex for rails validations. Implementing some of these rules is difficult or impossible if I only look at the logged in user's status. The current solution is to create a Security class that will accept a database object and a user and either allow or disallow the action to take place.

If I follow this course of action the implementation is going to be nasty. Right now I'm looking at something like this

```
#For every field on an object passed to Security::allow?(user, object), call this private method
def allow_helper?(user, object, field) 
    perm = permissions[user.rank][object.class.name][field] 
    if perm.is_a? Array
          perm.include? object.send(field)
    else
          perm
```

Which is going to very quickly become a nightmare to maintain. There has got to be an alternative to this nightmare I've dreamed up. I stopped myself before I coded this.

Comment: Might be helpful to explain why this is too complex for validation, which seems the obvious answer.

Comment: I guess I feel that using validations for security would be mixing logic that I didn't want mixed. Perhaps it isn't the issue I thought it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a `Permissions` model, and then simply see if `user.permissions.find(:permission_name_here)` when you design the validations and views?

Comment: You mean something like http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin/tree/master/